# can Protractor/Jasmine wait for 20 minutes for test execution?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, jenkins-pipeline, timeout

Test requires to get an updated value after 20 minutes. Until then some dummy steps will be done. Is this possible? Will Jenkins be alright with this?

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you want other tests to run while the current test is waiting for the value to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

yes, possible, jenkins will run whatever you tell it to run

On protractor side though make sure to set these in your config

```
exports.config = {

    // Before performing any action, Protractor waits until there are no pending asynchronous tasks in your Angular application
    allScriptsTimeout: 21 * 60 * 1000,

    // Set Protractor timeout
    getPageTimeout: 21 * 60 * 1000,

    jasmineNodeOpts: {

        // If an 'it' block takes longer than the timeout for any reason (even legitimate), it will fail
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 21 * 60 * 1000,
    }
};
```

For more info go here https://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts